# Erlang and epmd installation from binary has circular dependency

Tags: erlang, epmd

Pardon my English.

I am trying to install Erlang 23 on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server Version 12 Patch 3 which is not connected to Internet so I cannot use zypper or wget and **have** to install it manually using binary.

I get the below errors :

- `erlang-epmd is needed by erlang-23.0.2-1.2.x86_64` when installing erlang.
- `erlang = 23.0.2 is needed by erlang-epmd-23.0.2-1.2.x86_64` when installing erlang-empd.

How to resolve this circular dependency?

Comment: It would be useful to show the installation command(s) you're attempting to use. Also, have you tried installing both rpms in the same command?

Comment: Thank you. I was using rpm. I was new to its usage and totally missed the multi-installation option. Thank you. rpm -i *.rpm (or listing the 2 rpm files) fixed the issue. Is there anway to upvote your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install codependent RPMs by putting them together in the same command, e.g.:

```
rpm -iv erlang-23.0.2-1.2.x86_64.rpm erlang-epmd-23.0.2-1.2.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you. Accepted and up-voted (though my clout is very less to be seen).